# Pandas - concatenate values from identifiers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to make a comprehensive dataframe in pandas, based of data that is structured around identifiers.

My input dataframe:

```
>>> data = [['x', '34H52'], ['x', '38B55'], ['y',  '34H52'], ['y', '38B55'], ['z', '38B55'], ['z', '38B55']]                                                        
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['identifier', 'data'])                    
>>> df                                                                      
  identifier   data
0          x  34H52
1          x  38B55
2          y  34H52
3          y  38B55
4          z  38B55
5          z  38B55
```

I need to concatenate the values by identifiers.

My desired output:

```
  identifier         data
0          x  34H52,38B55
1          y  34H52,38B55
2          z  38B55,38B55
```

I'm not very experienced with pandas so I was wondering if this is possible directly with pandas and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
>>> df                                                                      
  identifier   data
0          x  34H52
1          x  38B55
2          y  34H52
3          y  38B55
4          z  38B55
5          z  38B55
```

you can group by the identifier and then apply `str.join` in the aggregation step.

```
>>> df.groupby('identifier', as_index=False).agg(lambda s: ','.join(s))     
   identifier        data
0          x  34H52,38B55
1          y  34H52,38B55
2          z  38B55,38B55
```